# Webelement.click() clicks & then disappears &sendkeys() doesn't print anything in the textBox

Tags: selenium

Very new to Selenium!
I need to login to a portal src code is as below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <body title="">
</html>
```

Within body I have a login button as below

```
<div id="login-form:usernameDecoration">
  <div class="prop">
    <label class="name" for="login-form:usernameDecoration:username">Username:</label>
       <span class="value ">
         <span id="login-form:usernameDecoration:username" class="e-input">
             <input id="login-form:usernameDecoration:username" type="text"   name="login-form:usernameDecoration:username">
         </span>
        </span>
      <span class="rf-msgs error"> </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I could find the element i.e username textBox and also use .click() , but the cursor does not persist. It simply vanishes. And when I execute sendKeys("username"). It does not appear on the textbox. Strange thing is there is no exception, my test passes. 
Moroever, I tried the ways mentioned in the some of the questions in stackOverflow itself, but nothing works out. There is no frame tag, everything is on a single page within  only. So there is no switchto also. Please help me out! Selenium is not that straightForward as it seems!! :-)

Does the tag  make any difference, I mean can I still use sendKeys() function. I can click the button on the same  but unable to send any text. I am trying to understand why but don't know.

Comment: From your description are you clicking on the input element and then sending text? With Selenium you shouldn't need to click on it first. You should just be able to `.sendKeys()` directly to the element.

Comment: No, I double checked, I simply tried sendKeys(), but still does not.work :-( Then only  I tried enabling,clicking then sendingKeys. But nothing worked. strange thing is there  are no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that complicated at all. Where is your code?? What did you write to identify and perform action on the elements??

If you want to enter text in the text box, use following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login-form:usernameDecoration:username")).sendKeys("xyz");
```

I think you tried sending text to the label instead of text box, but the text was not filled in the text box. You have to enter the text in the element for the text box itself.

Comment: @husam- No I did not click on the label,I double checked that, thats why I said cursor appears and vanishes within milliSecs. Here is my code snippet:WebElement userName=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-form:usernameDecoration:username']"));username.sendKeys("xys");I also tried enabling it and then clicking and then sendKeys(), but nothing worked :-((

Comment: Starnge thing is with Xpath I am not able to sendKeys, however with Id I tried, I am able to sendKeys. I mean for selenium does it make any difference.

Comment: Yes it did in your case. As doug pointed out, you have two elements with same id. Your xpath was //*[...] here star means any tag which matches the id given, in your case 1st match came with span and not input. If your xpath was //input[@id='login-form:usernameDecoration:us‌​ername'], it would have worked fine.

Comment: Thanks!!So, that means I can not take the firepath directly, how can I avoid such things? Is manual validation the only way?

Comment: No you can not take firepath directly. To avoid such thing make sure that the locator (not only xpath, any locator) is unique for the element you want to access. To check whether your xpath is unique, you can simply use the count of nodes found by firepath, when you hit evaluate button. If number of nodes found by firepath is greater than 1, your xpath is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my code snippet:WebElement
>   userName=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-form:usernameDecoration:us‌​ername']"));username.sendKeys("xys");

I do believe that's return you the span element:
`<span id="login-form:usernameDecoration:username" class="e-input">`

You have two elements with the same id. Make sure you're looking for the INPUT with that id and not the span. //input[@id='login-form:usernameDecoration:us‌​ername']